# Evaluate all pair combinations in an array for a condition in n log n time complexity

Tags: algorithms

Task - Consider an array of n elements. Count the number of pairs that satisfy condition X (sum of the two elements < an arbitrary number, k) .

The basic approach I could think of would be O(n^2), where I evaluate all n*(n-1)/2 pairs. How can I solve the problem in a better time frame i.e., O(n log n) or less?

The best approach so far was to sort the array, find where a+b smaller than k then add indice of a to solution. But the process still has to go through n-1 'b's to check for each of them. It's better but still doesn't improve the worst case.

Also, this isn't homework. I came across this while preparing for a competition.

Comment: As long as there is no restriction what the condition might be, there very likely is no faster way. If the condition is (anti-)symmetric and transitive there might be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you need ALL results on an arbitrary condition (say `C(a,b) = (sha1(a~c)^sha1(c~a))%2 == 0` with `~` as concatenation) then there are n*(n-1)/2 values you need to output that are all independent; so no there is no better way,

but if the result of one pair tells you something about the result of another pair then that information can be used to speed things up. like in your example if sum > k then you sort and for each number you check each in order (forwards or backwards). On the first true result you add the numbers still remaining. This will be `O(n log n + r)` with r number of true results.

**edit**: on second thought you can use a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search) each on each number `a` find the first number that is larger than `k-a` reducing it to a `O(n log n)` completely

Comment: I've tried that approach. Sort the array, find where a+b<k then add indice of a to solution. But the process still has to go through n-1 'b's to check for each of them. It's better but still doesn't improve the worst case.

Comment: @7Aces I found a better approach see my edit

Comment: @ratchetfreak In order to perform binary search, you must first organize it into a binary tree which takes O(n log n) time.  If you repeat binary searches for n objects, you get `O(n log n + n log n)` or `O(2 n log n)` time.  Which, while better, [it is not much better than `O(n^2)`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%5E2+%3D+2*n*log+n) unless we're talking about very large values of *n*.

Comment: @Neil: O(2 n log n) = O(n log n). So unless we really inspect the constant factors involved, we can't really tell anything more based on just the big-O notation.

Comment: @Neil even [n as low as 100 gives a big difference](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+n^2%3B+2*n*log+n+from+0+to+100)

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes, O(2 n log n) = O(n log n), however the point of that is to emphasize that it takes twice as long.  Theory is only as good as how you apply it, and if he's trying to reduce times, it may interest him to know that it takes twice as long which is why I wrote it as such.

Comment: @Neil: no, we can't say that it's twice as long! That depends on the constant factors. If *one* O(n log n) operation has a constant factor (multiplier) of 5 and the other has one of 1, then they are together "O(2 n log n) = O(n log n)" but together only take 1.2 times as long as the first one alone. *Either* you look at *all* the precise performance characteristics (and thus leave big-O-land) or you stick to the rules and discard the constant factors.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Now you're just being pedantic.  Big O notation is fine and good for theory, but if it is being used to denote algorithms which perform better, you cannot just ignore constant factors because you're using Big O notation since that defeats the purpose of communicating performance of a particular algorithm which is kind of the whole point of the post.

Comment: @Neil: I agree: for practical applications pure Big O is a starting point and not the end-all. I'm just saying that "it takes twice as long" is just as wrong as ignoring all constant factors.

Comment: @Neil if you step away from Big O then you are doing profiling. doing theoretical profiling is a exercise in futility because it depends on too many thing that are impossible to control

Comment: @ratchetfreak: that's exactly what I was trying to say, well said. I like the term "theoretical profiling" ;-)

Comment: @ratchetfreak The Binary Search approach worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> Given an array *A* of length *n* and a bound *k* find all indices
>   *(i,j)* such that *A[i] + A[j] < k*.

This can actually be solved in *O(n log n)*.

The set *I* of indices *(i,j)* you are looking for has some structure
when the array is sorted in increasing order.  Indeed if *(i₀,j₀)*
belongs to *I* then, whenever *i ≤ i₀* and *j ≤ j₀* the indice pair
*(i,j)* also belongs to *I*.  This means that *I* looks like this:

```
...........
++*........
+++........
+++........
+++........
+++........
+++++*.....
++++++.....
++++++++*..
+++++++++..
```

where a dot `.` denotes a pair that does not belong to *I* while a
plus `+` or a star `*` denotes a pair belonging to *I*.  As you see,
the presence of an indice denoted `+` is implied by the presence of
some indice denoted by a star `*` so only the latter need to be
searched.

1. Sort the array in *O(n log n)*
2. Set *i* to the largest indice so that *A[i] ≤ k* in *O(n)* and set
   *j* to 1 if you use Pascal or 0 if you use another language, this
   latter operation is *O(1)*.
3. If *A[i] + A[j]* is greater than *k* then decrease *i* and try 3.
   again, otherwise go to 4.
4. If *A[i] + A[j+1]* is smaller than *k* then increase *j* and try 4. again.
5. We have found a point marked with a `*` add it to *I* and decrease
   *i*.
6. If *A[i] + A[j+1]* is greater than *k* then decrease *i* and try 6. again.
7. Go to 4.

Do not forget to fix the algorithm and add boundary checking and
adequate exit conditions. In the repetitive part 3.-7. the algorithm
only visits indices that are on the frontier between *I* and its
complement.  This frontier has length at most *2n* so the overall cost
of this exploration is *O(n)*.  The repetitive part 3.-7. is just a contrived way to say: visit that frontier, remembering whenever you have to change direction.

The total cost of the algorithm is then *O(n log n) + O(n) + O(1) +
O(n) = O(n log n)*.

P.S.: Actually the picture should be symmetric around the first diagonal and the algorithm can stop exploring the frontier when it meets the diagonal.  These are small details.

P.P.S.: Of course, if your condition does not have structure, you must explore all combinations.

Answer (score 2):

In that general way you explain it: no, can't be done.

As soon as you need to evaluate *all pair combinations* you pretty much have a O(n<sup>2</sup>) runtime.

If there is some way to exclude some combinations (for example for a given item, you know that no combination will fulfill the condition), then you can get better runtime behaviour.

For example, if you know the smallest number in your array to be *min*, then skipping all element *e* where *e + min > k* can help you get a better effective runtime (but it won't reduce the worst case).

Another approach that's useful if you don't need the best solution, but "good enough" is enough, is to use a heuristic. For example, if you can "guess" that a given item is *unlikely* to be in the ideal combination, you can skip it. This again will improve performance but can lead to you missing the ideal combination.

Comment: How about the particular condition X in the problem?